# why does my objective c method give me a "error: can not use an object as parameter to a method"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've looked at this over and over again and I can't see the problem.  Its probably obvious and I'm probably being an idiot and I apologize in advance for this.

In my interface I have:

```
@interface PolygonShape : NSObject 
{
    int numberOfSides;
    int minimumNumberOfSides;
    int maximumNumberOfSides;

}

@property int numberOfSides, minimumNumberOfSides, maximumNumberOfSides;

// class methods
+ (float)getAngleInDegrees:(PolygonShape *) polyshape;
+ (float)getAngleInRadians:(PolygonShape *) polyshape;
+ (NSString)getName:(PolygonShape *) polyshape;

//instance methods
- (id)init;
- (id)initWithNumberOfSides:(int)sides minimumNumberOfSides:(int)min 
       maximumNumberOfSides:(int)max;
@end
```

The part in the implementation that I get errors is for the getName method:

```
@implentation...

+ (NSString)getName:(PolygonShape *) polyshape
{
// here is where I get the "error: can not use an object as parameter to a method"
    int sides = [polyshape numberOfSides];
    NSString * s = [NSString init];

    switch (sides) {
        case 3:
            s = "@Triangle";
// there's also an "assignment from incompatible pointer type" warning...but its secondary
            break;
        case 4:
            return "@Square";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The thing that drives me batty is that the class methods works just fine:

```
+ (float)getAngleInDegrees:(PolygonShape *) polyshape;
+ (float)getAngleInRadians:(PolygonShape *) polyshape;
```

Comment: init is an instance method, not a class method. You need to create an instance by sending alloc to the class, then send init to that new instance. Thus: [[NSString alloc] init]. Also, you don't need the s variable at all, since you're not using it. You can then replace the assignment under case 3 with a return statement (like the one under case 4).

Comment: Thanks Peter - you're absolutely right.  It might make sense to just use [NSString new] but that seems to be discouraged from what I've read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your getName: method should return (NSString *), not (NSString). I assume this is the error; if so, then yes, the error message could definitely have been more informative.

In fact, in Objective-C you will never see objects getting passed around without their * behind them, not as return values, not as parameters, not as local variables and not as member variables.

BTW, the warning you mention is because you have a typo, mixing up "@foo" with @"foo". The latter is an Objectice-C string literal, the former is a C string literal whose first character just happens to be @.

Comment: You're absolutley right on both counts.  Thanks you for helping save my sanity.

You right - I'm passing the pointer not the object which I have to indicate with the *.  I don't understand why it also makes a difference if its (NSString *) foo or (NSString ) *foo (wouldn't the second form be more correct in showing foo to be a pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure about the details, but the way I think about it is that as long as you're dealing with ObjC classes, the parentheses and the asterisk are just a special syntax meant to resemble C's pointer syntax. So the ObjC parser handles them with special rules. That might not be technically correct, but probably a good way to think about it while learning.

Comment: ube: The * is part of the type specification, and the whole type specification must be inside the ().

Comment: Thanks harms and Peter - I'll keep that in mind.  Especially that "objective C" is not "C" - its obvious...but the syntactic nuances can cause quite a bit of trip ups.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, you're using `[NSString init]` where you should be using `[[NSString alloc] init]`. However, that will only allocate an empty string, so you'd probably be better off initializing s to either `@""` or `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is slightly misleading in this case. In Objective-C, it's generally not possible to pass an object by value (including return values). In this case, you declare the return value as `NSString` rather than `NSString*`. The declaration should be:

```
+ (NSString*)getName:(PolygonShape *) polyshape
```

not

```
+ (NSString)getName:(PolygonShape *) polyshape
```

Comment: Thank you Barry - you're right.  I'm passing a pointer back to an object.